# Some basic Comet/Jquery questions?

Tags: jquery, comet

My questions are: What's a meta, what do subscribe and unsubscribe do, and what does startBatch/endBatch do?

Comment: How is it jQuery related? meta?

Comment: I don't know Comet, so I won't post this as an answer, but here are links to the documentation that seems to answer your questions. http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-javascript/subscription http://cometd.org/node/55